# img.onload is not keeping the same size javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, onload

I have array of base64 images im using img.onload method to resize them, im passing the width and the height through  img.width and img.height but im always ending with same width and height of the last image.

I tried this answer [JavaScript loop/scope issue with Image.onload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741023/javascript-loop-scope-issue-with-image-onload)

 didn't work for me

```
var list = myimgs.length;
var base64List = [];
var myJSON;
  if(list != 0){
    for(var i = 0; i <list; i++){             
       var count = 0;  
       var img = new Image;
       img.onload = resizeImage();
       img.src = myimgs[i].src; 
       img.width= myimgs[i].width;
       img.height= myimgs[i].height;

   function resizeImage() {
      if((document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML.indexOf("base64") != -1)){
      emailBody = emailBody.replace(/<img src="data:image[^>]*>/g,"imageTag");
        var x = img.width;
        var y = img.height;

   var newDataUri = imageToDataUriWithoutChangingEquality(this, x, y);
   var base64 = newDataUri.match(/data:(.+);base64,(.+)/);
   var base64Number = Math.round((base64[2].length )*3/4);
   var dateTime = new Date().toLocaleString()

        var tmpDocument = {
            sobjectType: "Document",
            Name: 'Image ' +dateTime,
            ContentType:  'image/png',
            Body: base64[2]
            };
   base64List.push(tmpDocument);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(tmpDocument));
   myJSON = JSON.stringify(base64List);
        }
   count++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958078/resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas

Comment: @AngelLuis it required me to have img.onload function

Comment: You shouldn't attach a callback to the Event instead of call to the function? `img.onload = resizeImage;`. I'm not used to use the `on...` method, I prefer to use `addEventListener`.